# Dynamic RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite dynamic rewrite url I want to change url

```
www.mysite.com/page.php?title=About Us
with this
www.mysite.com/about-us
```

I did is manually like this

```
RewriteRule ^about-us$ page.php?title=About\ Us [NC,L]
```

But I want it should be dynamic for new coming new pages I dont want to add manually links to htaccess

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ flights-detail1.php?dest=$1
```

But its not working for me. Need experts advice please

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect all your pages:

```
www.mysite.com/about-us
www.mysite.com/other
www.mysite.com/etc
```

like this

```
www.mysite.com/page.php?title=about-us
```

in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^page\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I just test here with one server, that work well... See if your ftp software has sent the .htaccess file in text mode (not binary)

Comment: It is showing blank page no any data. Just like I am browsing page.php instead of page.php?title=about-us

Comment: In this case the `RewriteRule` work. Try to show in your `page.php` what is the `title`... or `phpinfo();`

Comment: I don't know its not showing any result. Don't have any idea why.

Comment: I have a mysql query on the page this one: $req_page = $_REQUEST['title']; $page_query = mysql_query("SELECT `page_meta_title`, `page_meta_description`, `page_meta_keywords`, `page_title`, `page_text` FROM `pages` WHERE `page_name`='$req_page'");
$page_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($page_query);

Comment: Try to add that on the top of the PHP result page: `phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT|INFO_VARIABLES);` and after that, you can see if `title` is correct or not after `RewriteRule`

Comment: This one htaccess code is working for me: RewriteRule ^([^-]*)\.htm$ /page.php?id=$1 [L] but is not replacing space with - its showing like this mysite.com/about us.htm instead of mysite.com/about-us.htm please advice

Comment: Or, in your PHP page, you can change that `$req_page = $_REQUEST['title'];` with `$req_page = strtr($_REQUEST['title'], "-", " ");`

Comment: I tried it already but its not working for me. showing page not found

Comment: Here is my htaccess code: RewriteRule ^([^-]*)\.htm$ /page.php?id=$1 [L] and here is my page code: $req_page = strtr($_REQUEST['title'], "-", " ");
$page_query = mysql_query("SELECT `page_meta_title`, `page_meta_description`, `page_meta_keywords`, `page_title`, `page_text` FROM `pages` WHERE `page_name`='$req_page'"); please check where is problem ?

Comment: Use my `.htaccess`. With yours, you don't redirect the final part of the link about**-us**